# Get PID from tasklist command

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, pid, tasklist

I am using tasklist to bring me information about a specific service/proccess running on my Windows Server.

The command:

```
tasklist /svc /fi "SERVICES eq .Service02"
```

The output:

```
Image Name           PID      Services
================== ======== ============================================
app02.exe           15668    .Service02
```

I searched for quite a while now here on StackOverflow, other forums and also on Windows Docs but I couldn't figure out how to get the desired output, which is:

```
15668
```

I managed to do a command that kind of worked but not really...

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims= " %A in ('tasklist /svc /fi "SERVICES eq .Service02"') do echo %B
```

This did not give me the desired output - Instead, it gave me the following output:

```
C:\Users\admin>echo Name
Name

C:\Users\admin>echo ========
========

C:\Users\admin>echo 15668
15668
```

If I could only do something that only echoed the third line. The output would be exactly what I need. The PID.

So, I need a command that brings the name of the proccess being used by the service I provide, and return me only its PID.

Please, can someone help me?

**Edit**: Thanks to @Squashman I managed to do a new command:

```
tasklist /svc /fi "SERVICES eq .Service02" /FO csv /NH
"service02.exe","15668",".Service02"
```

And now the output is:

```
"service02.exe","15668",".Service02"
```

But where do I go from here?

Comment: Should be pretty easy if you have tasklist output as a CSV and suppress the column header.

Comment: I didnt know about CSV output and NH parameter.

Comment: tasklist /svc /fi "SERVICES eq .Service02" /FO csv /NH So, i did it like this... But how do i get the second cell which is PID?

Comment: You already answered that yourself in your question with the `FOR /F` command.;

Comment: I tried using the for i did but instead of getting PID i got "PID". Any ideas on how to remove the quotes?

Comment: We seem to be having a lot of read the manual moments.  Open up a command prompt and type: `for /?` to read the help file.  Maybe you will find this interesting. `%~I         - expands %I removing any surrounding quotes (")`

Comment: Thanks that did it. Do you want to answer below so i can mark your answer as the best?

Comment: Could I please ask for what purpose you require the Process Identifier?

Comment: maybe this command can help you `wmic service where (name = ".Service02") get ProcessId |More +1`

Comment: Hello @Compo ! How are you doing? Yes, of course. I will use the output to make a item and then a Trigger Expression in Zabbix. Ex: If the memory of the proccess with PID 1234 exceeds 1500MB i will restart it.

Comment: Hello @Daemon-5 . Hello. I did this but it gave me two lines - ProccesId and then the PID... Is it possible to remove the first line? Also, is there a ProcessMem parameter to get memory too instead of PID?

Comment: @RaulChiarella, thanks for your reply, but You didn't make clear why you needed the PID. The only thing I can think of is that you are using the PID to perform another check on the memory used by a process which has that identifier. _If that is the case, my first instinct is that you would probably already know the image name too_. However, what if your service has dependents? would their accumulated totals need to be incorporated when determining the limit for your bytecount, before trying to restart the service. Whilst you have an answer here already, I think that your process may be flawed.

Comment: The `tasklist` command can also output the memory usage. So just adjust the options to do so.

Comment: In my case the proccess only uses one service. But there are multiple proccesses with the same name so i can not use proccess name. It has to be PID... The service names are unique tho - So i wanted to know the PID using the service name, then with the output get the memory from that PID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a [`for /F` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) to capture the CSV output of the `tasklist` command and to extract the right token.

In Command Prompt:

```cmd
@for /F "tokens=2 delims=," %P in ('tasklist /SVC /FI "Services eq .Service02" /FO CSV /NH') do @echo %~P
```

In a batch file:

```cmd
@echo off
for /F "tokens=2 delims=," %%P in ('
    tasklist /SVC /FI "Services eq .Service02" /FO CSV /NH
') do echo %%~P
```

The [`~`-modifier](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) removes the surrounding quotation marks from the PID value.

Comment: for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=," %A in ('tasklist /svc /fi "SERVICES eq .Service02" /FO csv /NH') do @echo %~B This is the command i did. It worked, now i can move on to the next step :)

Comment: The next step is: Get memory usage of process that has that PID. Example: tasklist /fi "pid eq 15668" ... But instead of using directly the PID name i use the result of the command above. I will take a look into this and if i dont discover how to do it i will open another topic here on StackOverflow 

Answer (score 1):

You could of course retrieve the PID using the Service Control executable, `sc.exe` instead.

```sh
@For /F "Tokens=3" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\sc.exe QueryEx .Service02 ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe "PID" 2^>NUL') Do @Set "PID=%%G"
```

However, based upon [your reply in comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68944725/get-pid-from-tasklist-command?noredirect=1#comment121867211_68944725), here's a quick example to show you how you may be able to perform the task without any need for retrieving the PID:

```sh
@Set "SvcName=.Service02"
@Set "SysDir=%SystemRoot%\System32"
@Rem Stop service if memory usage is greater than or equal to 150 MB
@%SysDir%\tasklist.exe /Fi "Services Eq %SvcName%" /Fi "MemUsage GE 153600" /Fo CSV /NH /Svc | %SysDir%\findstr.exe /I /R ",\"%SvcName%\"$" 1>NUL && (
    %SysDir%\sc.exe Stop %SvcName%
    Rem Add a delay to give the service time to stop
    %SysDir%\timeout.exe /T 5 /NoBreak 1>NUL
    Rem If service state is stopped then start service again
    %SysDir%\sc.exe Query %SvcName% | %SysDir%\findstr.exe /R /C:"STATE  *: 1 " 1>NUL && %SysDir%\sc.exe Start %SvcName%)
```

Line `7` can be adjusted to increase the timeout period from `5` seconds as needed.

Comment: Hello. I am not sure if the way i did was the best but this is my final command: for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,5 delims= " %A in ('tasklist /fi "pid eq %PID%" /NH') do @echo %E

Comment: It does exactly what i need... I needed to created the variable PID using the command for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=," %A in ('tasklist /svc /fi "SERVICES eq .Service02" /FO csv /NH') do @Set "PID=%~B"

Comment: Any idea how to convert the memory output from comma to column? Instead of getting 1,170,420 i get 1.170.420 ...

Comment: Also i can not use the command above because the expression "Is greater than" will be used in Zabbix. So i will have multiple outcomes from the same result - If its too low i will do THIS and if its too high i will just output a warning on the screen... A warning and a alarm sound.

Comment: Also... Is it possible to use just one line to make those two commands?

Comment: Are you expecting me to answer all of your new questions here despite you not using any of the code I've submitted? Where is my motivation for doing so? My lower code example above can easily be added to with no other changes, to allow for running a different command if the memory usage was less that 150MB. Simply suffix `|| (your code here)` to the last line. What you may, or may not, be doing with Zabbix has no bearing whatsoever on how this simple code works, and is irrelevant.

Comment: Thank you, i just added your code to the batch script i made. It worked like a charm... Thanks! All answers here helped me.

Comment: Bro i just made a new question regarding something that has to do with the question i made here, but its not the same question. The next step now is to remove the commas on the output...

Comment: I would also like to state that if there is something that i did not use its because i didnt understood how it works and couldnt understand its 'logic'.